Is it possible to keep the connection alive and send the response in pieces with laravel?
I want to keep the connection alive and responding line by line to the client much like a live log, like this:
for ($id = 0; $id < 100; $id++) {
    $response = Http::get("http://api.example.com/user/{$id}");

    response()->send('['.Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s')."] - {$response->status()} - {$response->body()}");
}

return response()->send('All requests done');

In that case, Laravel would send a request to an api and it would result in a line being sent back to the client listening, until the request is truly done by returning a response();
This would behave like an artisan command, outputting to the console a line with the current progress with $this->line('bla'), but for http requests.
Although I can just concatenate to a single string and return the string in the end, it would be better to inform the user as the process is running.

Generally http requests don`t support described behaviour, for implementing something like a live log probably the best way is to use websockets which supported in laravel broadcasting feature: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/broadcasting.
You can initialise processing of ur data using http request and the listen websokets for monitoring progress from client

WebSockets are a good suggestion, but it's not quite true that normal HTTP can't do this - if you "flush" each line of output to the browser, it will be rendered on screen immediately. I've no idea what that would look like in Laravel, rather than pure PHP, though.
